# SQL products/productsales

Tags: sql, inner-join

A common (i assume?) type of query:

I have two tables ('products', 'productsales'). Each record in 'productsales' represents a sale (so it has 'date', 'quantity', 'product_id'). How do i efficiently make a query like the following:

Retrieve the product names of all products that were sold more than X times between date Y and date Z.

(X is the quantity sold not the number of transactions)

Comment: More clarity on what you mean by "X times" needed, number of transactions or quantity sold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT p.[name]
 FROM products p
 WHERE p.product_id in (SELECT s.product_id
     FROM productsales s
     WHERE s.[date] between @dateStart and @dateEnd
     GROUP BY s.product_id
     HAVING Sum(s.quantity) > @X )
```

Comment: I presume you'll have to use SUM instead of COUNT, since the Sales table has a qty field ... :)

Comment: Fredrik, The question asks for the number of times sold, not the number of items.

Comment: The question is perhaps vague on this it asks for times but includes the detail that a qty field is available. I've ask Mota for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

The above query is not entirely correct ...

```
SELECT Name FROM Products
WHERE ProductId IN
( SELECT ProductId 
  FROM ProductSales
  WHERE ProductSales.Date BETWEEN  Y AND Z 
  GROUP BY ProductId
  HAVING SUM(ProductSales.Qty) > x
)
```

Comment: Note most answers are view by votes so 'above' is arbitary.  Also it depends on how you interpret the questions use of the phrase "sold more than X times".  You could be right it might refer to qty sold but it could also refer to the number of specific transactions.

Comment: Note that the "above query" is going to change in this thread over time, making your "above query" reference incorrect...

Comment: I was referring to the query written by Mehrdad Afshari; which couldn't even be interpreted since it has incorrect syntax.

Comment: I would seem your original interpretation of the question was correct +1.

Comment: Fredrik, I have tried the query on SQL Server 2008 and there is no "incorrect syntax" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you should learn the [group by statement](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/COUNTandGROUPBY.htm)

The simplest statement would be:

```
SELECT ps.product_id, COUNT(*) 
           FROM product_sales ps 
           WHERE ps.product_id = id AND ps.Date BETWEEN @Y AND @Z
           GROUP_BY product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.[name]
FROM
products p
INNER JOIN
productsales ps
ON 
p.id = ps.product_id
WHERE
ps.date BETWEEN @Y AND @Z
GROUP BY
p.[name] 
--,p.id if it is likely that you have two products with the same name
HAVING
SUM(ps.quantity) > @X
```

Tested successfully with [MS AdventureWorks DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124659.aspx), using the following-

```
DECLARE @Y DATETIME, @Z DATETIME, @X INT    

SET @Y = '2004-06-09'
SET @Z = '2004-08-01'
SET @X = 100

    SELECT p.[Name]
    FROM
    Production.Product p
    INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail ps
    ON 
    p.ProductID = ps.ProductID
    WHERE
    ps.ModifiedDate BETWEEN @Y AND @Z
    GROUP BY p.Name
    HAVING
    SUM(ps.OrderQty) > @X
```

Comment: True, I have made that assumption

Comment: I have updated by including commented out p.id, in the event that two products have the same name. I don't think that I've ever come across this though